# How to jump to counterpart definition of current method in Xcode4 with shortcut key?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts

If a class defined as like this,

```
// A.h
@interface A
- (void)m1;  // I want to jumpt to here directly.
@end

// A.m
@implementation
- (void)m1
{
  // Caret here.
}
@end
```

I editor caret is places in method implementation body, is there a way to jump to it's definition directly with shortcut key? I can switch to header by pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>, however jumped position is not where I want.

Comment: Did **Command-Control-D** work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Just found it, Command-click on the function name.

**Edit2:** When I press command the function name turns into a link like the picture below:

[image: screenshot]

Clicking on it takes you to the definition and vice versa.

But since you're looking for a shortcut, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> takes you to the definition file and back. You have to put your cursor in the function name though.

**Later Edit:** Here's a [complete list](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html) of Xcode 4 keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I omitted the word 'shortcut key' on my question. And Command+Click it doesn't jump directly. It shows candidate list which slower than finding the method manually.. However thanks for answering!

Comment: I couldn't kind shortcut key, but your way was very useful. Thanks!